# Try to parse html table in iOS

Tags: html, ios, swift

I'm new in swift/iOS and I looking for best way to parse html table without `WebView` and display it on the screen. It is possible to do it with `NSMutableAttributedString` or `NSAttributedString`

Comment: Did you look for "NSAttributedString + html" at least?

Comment: Yeah, ofc. But it didn't work. Now i see that it works only for simple tables, for tables with attributes like cellspacing, cellpadding it's printing  
continuous text without columns

Comment: You could have said that. That you tried but not all effects where rendered. Well it doesn’t renderball html tags.

Comment: So did U know some way to parse html with these attrs?

Comment: Third party, webviews...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display the HTML table using UITextView.

```
@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let data = htmlString.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode),
        let attString = try? NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType : NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil) {
        lbl.attributedText = attString
        textView.attributedText = attString
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for your response! But I noticed that it works for simple table without cellspacing, cellpadding, colspan, etc. attributes. So, is exists in swift some option to ignore this html attributes?